# How can I sync Windows XP automatically to an NTP server?

Tags: ntp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to synchronize the clock of a windows server 2003 domain server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/13253/how-to-synchronize-the-clock-of-a-windows-server-2003-domain-server)

My server keeps losing a few seconds per week. I would like to automatically sync without the need for manual intervention

Comment: Need more info.  Is the server part of a Domain?  What OS is the server running?  etc...

Comment: Your... server.  Your Windows XP... server.  I keep saying it, and it still keeps making no sense.

Answer (score 1):

To update windows XP time, you only need to double-click on the clock, click on internet time tab, select to auto-sync and fill the box with a time server (time.windows.com for example).