# Time on Windows Server 2003 off by ten minutes

Tags: windows-server-2003, time-synchronization, time-server

I have a DC server that runs a network of about 20 computers. This is also the DC and pushes out the time to all the client computers.

However the time on the server is 10 minutes fast and is causing problems with some syncing applications. So far I have tried the regfix from MS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042

Next I tried to set an external server for time as per this technote:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784553.aspx

I updated the `/manualpeerlist` but whenever I run `w32tm /resync` it fetches the time but its always 10minutes too fast.

I'm stuck for ideas on how to debug this further.

Comment: Are the internal clients and the DC the same (ie. all are 10min fast according to the "external source") or are you saying the DC is 10min ahead of the 20 internal clients?

Comment: So you've synced your server to an external NTP source and all the client machines think it's 10 minutes fast? The real question is: Where are those client machines getting their time from, and why is that 10 minutes *slow*?

Comment: The DC is ten minutes fast and this gets pushed to all the clients. If I manually change the time on server or clients it will stick for about 15minutes and then it changes (presumably when it syncs to NTP) to 10mins fast.

Comment: When the DC syncs with the NTP, it updates exactly 10minutes ahead of the actual time

Comment: @Sammitch - that's why I asked the question in the comment.  This isn't what's happening.

Comment: What's the external time server you are using?  Can you post the verbose output of the w32tm sync on the DC with the external NTP server?  That would help see what is going on.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/az9J3f9s

Comment: Alex, that looks like a sync from client to DC unless I'm missing something.  On the DC, do "w32tm /query /status"

Comment: That log is from the DC not a client, although I suppose its possible that the DC is getting updated from somewhere else. How do I work this out though? I can't run /query because I think thats a Server 2008 only command. When I try to run it I get "Command /query is unknown"

Comment: Sorry I don't remember the 2003 commands.  w32tm /? should give you the various options.  Look here too:http://serverfault.com/questions/13253/how-to-synchronize-the-clock-of-a-windows-server-2003-domain-server?rq=1