# Problems setting NTP sever with w32tm for a DC that is a Hyper-V guest

Tags: hyper-v, time, ntp, synchronization

I have tried to sett my DC to get its time from several NTP severs. 
I follow this answer ([W32Time sync problems for Hyper-V Guests (W32Time Event IDs 38, 24, 29, 35)](https://serverfault.com/questions/24298/w32time-sync-problems-for-hyper-v-guests-w32time-event-ids-38-24-29-35/24299#24299)) to do it.

First I disable Time Synchronization in the Hyper-V Integration Services for each guest. Then restart the Windows Time serviceon the guest.

I had before this used this command: 
**w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"ntp.uio.no;timekeeper.
uio.no;nissen.uio.no;0.no.pool.ntp.org;1.no.pool.ntp.org;2.no.pool.ntp.org" /syn
cfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update**

And the cmd sad: The command completed successfully.

But the time was still 10 min wrong... I run w32tm again after restarted the DC without it having any effect. The **w32tm /query /status** still say: "Source: Local CMOS Clock"

---

FROM MY CMD:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator.MHG>w32tm /query /status

Leap Indicator: 0(no warning)

Stratum: 1 (primary reference - syncd by radio clock)

Precision: -6 (15.625ms per tick)

Root Delay: 0.0000000s

Root Dispersion: 10.0000000s

ReferenceId: 0x4C4F434C (source name:  "LOCL")

Last Successful Sync Time: 05.09.2009 20:06:21

Source: Local CMOS Clock

Poll Interval: 6 (64s)


C:\Users\Administrator.MHG>w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"ntp.uio.no;timekeeper.
uio.no;nissen.uio.no;0.no.pool.ntp.org;1.no.pool.ntp.org;2.no.pool.ntp.org" /syn
cfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update

The command completed successfully.

C:\Users\Administrator.MHG>w32tm /query /status

Leap Indicator: 0(no warning)

Stratum: 1 (primary reference - syncd by radio clock)

Precision: -6 (15.625ms per tick)

Root Delay: 0.0000000s

Root Dispersion: 10.0000000s

ReferenceId: 0x4C4F434C (source name:  "LOCL")

Last Successful Sync Time: 05.09.2009 20:06:21

Source: Local CMOS Clock

Poll Interval: 6 (64s)


C:\Users\Administrator.MHG>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with the way you specify the peers.

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757721%28WS.10%29.aspx) says :

> When specifying multiple peers, use a space as the delimiter and enclose them in quotation marks.